# Selenium: http://localhost:4444/wd/hub returns a NullPointerException, what am I doing incorrectly

Tags: java, c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Given: Attempting to use a RemoteWebDriver in C# with this code.

```
var url = new Uri("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub");
var wd = new RemoteWebDriver(url, DesiredCapabilities.Chrome());
```

The new RemoteWebDriver code above doesn't respond until there's a timeout...

**More Details**

I've started my Hub with these parameters to the Selenium Server:

```
-jar "C:\SomeFolder\selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar" -port 4444 -role hub
```

And registered a Node using these parms..

```
-jar "C:\SomeFolder\selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar" -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -port 9662
```

**Debugging**

If I type in this URL after starting the Hub, It shows there is a registered Node:

http://location:4444/grid/console

But when typing in this url after starting the Hub

http://localhost:4444/wd/hub

The browser shows this java (json) stack trace pointing to ExternalSessionKey.java

```
{"status":13,"value":{"class":"java.lang.NullPointerException","stackTrace":[{"fileName":"ExternalSessionKey.java","className":"org.openqa.grid.internal.ExternalSessionKey","methodName":"fromWebDriverRequest","lineNumber":77},{"fileName":"WebDriverRequest.java","className":"org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.WebDriverRequest","methodName":"extractSession","lineNumber":62},{"fileName":"RequestHandler.java","className":"org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.RequestHandler","methodName":"getSession","lineNumber":231},{"fileName":"RequestHandler.java","className":"org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.RequestHandler","methodName":"process","lineNumber":118},{"fileName":"DriverServlet.java","className":"org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet","methodName":"process","lineNumber":83},{"fileName":"DriverServlet.java","className":"org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet","methodName":"doGet","lineNumber":61},{"fileName":"HttpServlet.java","className":"javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet","methodName":"service","lineNumber":687},{"fileName":"HttpServlet.java","className":"javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet","methodName":"service","lineNumber":790},{"fileName":"ServletHolder.java","className":"org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHolder","methodName":"handle","lineNumber":808},{"fileName":"ServletHandler.java","className":"org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler","methodName":"doHandle","lineNumber":587},{"fileName":"SessionHandler.java","className":"org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler","methodName":"doHandle","lineNumber":221},{"fileName":"ContextHandler.java","className":"org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler","methodName":"doHandle","lineNumber":1127},{"fileName":"ServletHandler.java","className":"org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler","methodName":"doScope","lineNumber":515},{"fileName":"SessionHandler.java","className":"org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler","methodName":"doScope","lineNumber":185},{"fileName":"ContextHandler.java","className":"org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler","methodName":"doScope","lineNumber":1061},{"fileName":"ScopedHandler.java","className":"org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler","methodName":"handle","lineNumber":141},{"fileName":"HandlerWrapper.java","className":"org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper","methodName":"handle","lineNumber":97},{"fileName":"Server.java","className":"org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.Server","methodName":"handle","lineNumber":499},{"fileName":"HttpChannel.java","className":"org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpChannel","methodName":"handle","lineNumber":310},{"fileName":"HttpConnection.java","className":"org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpConnection","methodName":"onFillable","lineNumber":257},{"fileName":"AbstractConnection.java","className":"org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.AbstractConnection$2","methodName":"run","lineNumber":540},{"fileName":"QueuedThreadPool.java","className":"org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool","methodName":"runJob","lineNumber":635},{"fileName":"QueuedThreadPool.java","className":"org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3","methodName":"run","lineNumber":555},{"className":"java.lang.Thread","methodName":"run","lineNumber":-1}]}}
```

Can anyone interpret the Stack Trace for me, and what to do to get this working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symptom of the issue was a connection timeout exception in this code.

```
var url = new Uri("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub");
var wd = new RemoteWebDriver(url, DesiredCapabilities.Chrome());
```

**Root Cause**

It was being caused because, during my debugging session; I ended the program prior to this statement:

```
wd.Quit();
```

Because my Hub was configured for only one node, the prior debug session still had an orphaned session on the hub.  Rebooting the Hub fixed that problem, but there's also the ability to configure as many Nodes as one wants.

Another fault of the Hub logic is that orphaned nodes are not cleaned up in the proper timeout as set in the configuration.  This causes orphaned nodes to remain alive for far longer than the timeout suggests... Check out the configuration options to see for yourself.  There should be an inactivity timer that says "if no activity in x secconds" kill the session.

**One Solution**

Make sure that (at a minimum) you configure your hubs to allow more nodes that you need while debugging your solution.

Comment: `Another fault of the Hub logic is that orphaned nodes are not cleaned up in the proper timeout as set in the configuration. This causes orphaned nodes to remain alive for far longer than the timeout suggests... Check out the configuration options to see for yourself. There should be an inactivity timer that says "if no activity in x secconds" kill the session`

I have a similar problem, can you let me know how to resolve this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47427026/orphaned-nodes-are-not-cleaned-up-after-waiting-more-than-the-specified-duration

Answer (score 14):

There is nothing wrong at your end.

The URL `http://localhost:4444/wd/hub` is designed such that it expects a PAYLOAD with your operation. Since you haven't provided the desired payload you are seeing a NullPointerException.

This URL is not supposed to be opened up in a browser. Its meant to be consumed via Http operations with a proper payload that adheres to the [Selenium w3c spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/)

Comment: Ok very good that explains the web browser stack trace when I type in the URL with nothing.  But the real issue deals with the time out I get trying to create a new RemoteWebDriver.  Would you have any hints on that part?

Comment: Can you pls share more info on what error you get when instantiating RemoteWebDriver ?

Comment: I was always getting timeouts.  I think the reason was that in my debugging environment I had left the browser requests up and running on subsequent sessions.  To fix that I needed to reset my hub and nodes everytime I kicked off the tests.  In production mode each IWebdriver would have been closed at the end of the test.